# get compared products and count in header

Tags: magento2, compare

I have a need to show products and count in header.phtml file [`Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml`] file.

How to access those products count and data staying in header.phtml file.

What i tried :

```
$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getCompareProducts();
```

Comment: How about your current issue?

Answer (score 3):

Count the item collection from helper:

```
$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getItemCollection()->count();
```

Retrieve compare list url:

```
$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getListUrl();
```

If we want to retrieve more information about items, we can build your own. A good sample here:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/CustomerData/CompareProducts.php**

```
 public function getSectionData()
 {
        $count = $this->helper->getItemCount();
        return [
            'count' => $count,
            'countCaption' => $count == 1 ? __('1 item') : __('%1 items', $count),
            'listUrl' => $this->helper->getListUrl(),
            'items' => $count ? $this->getItems() : [],
        ];
 }
```

Additionally, we also can get the compare list from the local storage: `localStorage.getItem('mage-cache-storage')`

JSON format:

[image: Compare items on local storage]

Comment: I have used your code but that is not working on catalog, cms & product page for me in case of guest user. but for compare page , cart page and checkout page it's working. Please help me.